# Cucumber test seems to be failing but doesn't acknowledge as such

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber

Since updating my gems, one of my cucumber tests appears to be failing i.e. in the one-line printout of test outcomes it prints a red F:

[image]

*However* the test summary shows that all the tests passed which seems to contradict the red F.

What's a good way to try and unwrap what's going on here and to get some output from that apparently failing test?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Run your tests with `cucumber --format=pretty ...` and check out the full output